# Skip failed steps in kubeflow pipeline and continue the pipeline

Tags: kubeflow-pipelines

Does anyone have an example how to handle failed steps in pipeline and continue pipeline even after failed step. ExitHandler can execute only the one, last step while I need to catch any possible failure i.e. something more like (pseudocode)

```py
step1 = comp_op1()
with dsl.Condition(even if step 1 failed)
 step2 = comp_op2()
 with dsl.Condition(even if step 2 failed)
   step3 = comp_op3()
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You would need an [ExitHandler](https://kubeflow-pipelines.readthedocs.io/en/stable/source/kfp.dsl.html#kfp.dsl.ExitHandler) to do this, it's made for it